# Make ListView from background of the stack scrollable

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a Stack that has some containers and horizontal listView at the very bottom of it.(Intentionally, it's a part of design). Now that I'm trying to scroll through it, it doesn't work because top container make it unreachable sort of. How can I remain the same widget tree but make the bottom listView scrollable?

```
return Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
      AnimatedBuilder(
                animation: ctrl,
        builder: (context, child){
          var pos = ctrl.position.pixels;
          return Container(
          height: pos<h?(pos/h * 250):250,
          child: ListView.builder(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            itemBuilder: (ctxt, index){
              return Container(
                height: pos<h?(pos/h * 250):250,
                width: 250,
                child: Image(), //Horizontal listview
              );
            },
          ),
          );
        },
        ),
      ListView(
        controller: ctrl,
        children: <Widget>[
          AnimatedBuilder(
            animation: ctrl,
            builder: (context, child){
              var pos = ctrl.position.pixels;
              return Container(
                height: pos<h?(pos/h * 250):250,
              );
            },
          ),
          //This is the container I'm talking about, it's just like padding(It's nothing in there)
        ],
      ),
    ],
  );
```

Comment: Can you give more details? Or maybe even add a screen shot of what you currently have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put the `ListView` after the `Container` in the order inside the `Stack`, so it will be over the `Container` and you can interact with it.

Or you could wrap the `Container` with `IgnorePointer`, so the gestures won't be intercepted by the `Container` and you could interact with the `ListView`.

Comment: Pablo, unfortunately the first option doesn't work for me, I mentioned that in the question. Second option doesn't seem to be working either. Are there any other solutions?

Comment: Could you put some code? Otherwise is difficult to help you. You may have another issue we are not seeing.

Comment: So, instead of wrapping the Container with IgnorePointer, you should wrap the ListView that contains the Container, with IgnorePointer

Comment: But how am I going to scroll the list then?)

Comment: You have 2 lists, you need to scroll both?

Comment: The one with images is horizontal, and the main is vertical(where a lot of other containers are.) I am making something like google maps app's place overview widget.

Comment: Then you should do the first option I put in my answer, I think you misunderstood it. You just have to change the order of the elements inside the Stack in the code, but it won't change the order visually. So, put the main ListView first and the AnimatedBuilder after that.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/pngRdhm this is the result I am trying to get. See, if I put it on top, it's going to stay there forever, but I have the animation of scrolling over it as it stays on one position

Comment: Please, post a minimal reproducible example so I can help you properly. I can't compile the code you posted.